# How do I index an ndarray using rows of another ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have

```
x = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3,3))
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6],
#        [7, 8, 9]])
```

and

```
ind = np.array([[1,1], [1,2]])
# array([[1, 1],
#        [1, 2]])
```

, how do I get use each row (axis 0) of `ind` to extract a cell of x? I hope to end up with the array `[5, 6]`. `np.take(x, ind, axis=0)` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ["advanced integer indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) by indexing `x` with two integer arrays, the first array for indexing the row, the second array for indexing the column:

```
In [58]: x[ind[:,0], ind[:,1]]
Out[58]: array([5, 6])
```

Comment: `ind` is actually huge. Is there any trick besides iteration?

Comment: There is no explicit iteration here. `ind[:,0]` is an example of NumPy basic slicing, which returns a view. Views are very fast to create since the underlying data is not copied.

Answer (score 1):

```
x[ind.T.tolist()]
```

works, too, and can also be used for multidimensional NumPy arrays.

## Why?

NumPy arrays are indexed by tuples. Usually, these tuples are [created implicitly by python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> #### Note
>
> In Python, `x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)]` is equivalent to `x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN];` the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

Note that this syntactic sugar isn't NumPy-specific. You could use it on dictionaries when the key is a tuple:

```
In [1]: d = { 'I like the number': 1, ('pi', "isn't"): 2}

In [2]: d[('pi', "isn't")]
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: d['pi', "isn't"]
Out[3]: 2
```

Actually, it's not even related to indexing:

```
In [5]: 1, 2, 3
Out[5]: (1, 2, 3)
```

Thus, for your NumPy array, `x = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))`

```
In [11]: x[1,2]
Out[11]: 6
```

because

```
In [12]: x[(1,2)]
Out[12]: 6
```

So, in [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31897024/674064), actually a tuple containing the columns of `ind` is passed:

```
In [21]: x[(ind[:,0], ind[:,1])]
Out[21]: array([5, 6])
```

with `x[ind[:,0], ind[:,1]]` just being an equivalent (**and recommended**) short hand notation for the same.

Here's how that tuple looks like:

```
In [22]: (ind[:,0], ind[:,1])
Out[22]: (array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]))
```

We can construct the same tuple diffently from `ind`: `tolist()` returns a NumPy array's rows. Transposing switches rows and columns, so we can get a list of columns by first transposing and calling `tolist` on the result:

```
In [23]: ind.T.tolist()
Out[23]: [[1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Because `ind` is symmetric in your example, it is it's own transpose. Thus, for illustration, let's use

```
In [24]: ind_2 = np.array([[1,1], [1,2], [0, 0]])
# array([[1, 1],
#        [1, 2],
#        [0, 0]])

In [25]: ind_2.T.tolist()
Out[25]: [[1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

This can easily be converted to the tuples we want:

```
In [27]: tuple(ind_2.T.tolist())
Out[27]: ([1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0])

In [28]: tuple(ind.T.tolist())
Out[28]: ([1, 1], [1, 2])
```

Thus,

```
In [29]: x[tuple(ind.T.tolist())]
Out[29]: array([5, 6])
```

equivalently to unutbu's answer for `x.ndim == 2` and `ind_2.shape[1] == 2`, but also working more generally when `x.ndim == ind_2.shape[1]`, in case you have to work with multi-dimensional NumPy arrays.

Why you can drop the `tuple(...)` and directly use the list for indexing, I don't know. Must be a NumPy thing:

```
In [43]: x[ind_2.T.tolist()]
Out[43]: array([5, 6, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been looking for this answer for a couple of days now and I was about to post this specific question.

Comment: FOLLOWUP: I just got the following error: `FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.` Do you know how to the same efficient indexing without the error?

Comment: @Sergio Well, the error message tells you to wrap the index sequence in a call to `tuple(...)`, so I'd try that.